# QC Journey Builder Output

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql

Is it possible to verify the output in each journey builder by using SQL to verify?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as this data is not exposed to any data view or API. Your best option is to check the history tab and drill down in the right hand panel